# how to outer join two tables?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have following tables:
tblA (id, price), tblB (id, minPay)
For example:

```
tblA
id        price
001       1.00
003       2.00

tblB
id        minPay
001       10.00
004       20.00
```

I need to somehow join this two tables to get following result:

```
id        price       minPay
001       1.00        10.00
003       2.00        0
004       0           20.00
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: FULL [OUTER] JOIN - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COALESCE()](https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=coalesce) to replace NULL with ZERO value

```
SELECT a.id, coalesce(a.price,0) AS Price, coalesce(b.minpay,0) as Minipay
FROM tblA a FULL OUTER JOIN tblB b 
ON a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a full outer join. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

```
SELECT tblA.id, tblA.price, tblB.minPay
FROM tblA
FULL OUTER JOIN tblB
ON tblA.id=tblB.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the expected result.

```
select tblA.id, price, minpay from tblA full outer join tblB on tblA-id=tblb.id
```

Answer (score 0):

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` will accomplish this, but I would assume you've got a master table which you could start with that contains all records, and then you're really better off starting there, then doing `LEFT JOIN`s. For example, assuming you have an `Items` table which contains all IDs (and assuming these are 1-1 relationships and not 1-many), then:

```
select
    i.id
    ,isnull(a.price, 0) [price]
    ,isnull(b.minPay, 0) [minPay]
from Items i
left join tblA a on i.id = a.id
left join tblB b on i.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this query

```
declare @tblA table (id varchar(50), price varchar(50))
insert into @tblA values ('001' ,'1.00'),('003','2.00')

declare @tblB table (id       int, minPay varchar(50))
insert into @tblB values ('001' ,'10.00'),('004','20.00')

select 
  case when b.id IS null then a.id else b.id end id , 
  case when b.minPay IS null then a.price else '0' end price, 
  isnull(minpay , 0) minpay
from @tblA a 
  full outer join @tblB b 
on A.id = b.id
```